# How can I recreate calling `super` in a delegate method implementation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a situation where I want to conditionally implement a delegate method depending on some run time configuration. Under some configurations I want to recreate what would happen if I had not implemented the delegate method at all.

Specifically, in the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:`, I want to provide a particular specialised string if one is known for the current language, but use the default behaviour otherwise, in which case iOS will use its translation of "Delete" to the current language.

If I override a method, then I can call `[super myMethod]` to call the default. How do achieve the same effect with a delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate methods won't generally have a `super` implementation to call.

Generally, the default behaviour is actually provided by the object that is delegating to your delegate (lets call that the "delegator"). The delegator provides the default behaviour in the case that its delegate does not implement the optional delegate method.

You need to convince the delegator that you don't have implementation of this delegate method, even when you do. You can achieve this by implementing `respondsToSelector:`.

In the case you give, your implementation will look like this:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector {
  // Is this the specific delegate method that is conditional?
  if(selector == @selector(tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:)) {
    const bool iWantToProvideAnImplementation = // Your logic here.
    return iWantToProvideAnImplementation;
  }
  else {
    // Use default behaviour.
    return [super respondsToSelector:selector];
  }
}
```

The delegate will now only call the optional method when `iWantToProvideAnImplementation` is true.

Comment: Nice self-answer, but beware it's not universal. *Some* delegating classes revert to a default behavior following a `respondsToSelector` check, but others prefer to make fallback behavior part of the API. (In fact, it kinda seems like that's what `UITableView` would want to do, since it allows the result to be nullable. Might be worth [filing a bug(http://bugreport.apple.com) about.)

Comment: Hey, @rickster, thanks for the comment! If you fancy writing a more comprehensive answer, I'd be happy to give you the tick. Otherwise, I'll see if I can improve mine in that case. I'll definitely try out your suggestion of simply returning `nil` to see if that provides the desired default behaviour.

Comment: Ah – I get what you mean :-) When you do return `nil` from that delegate method, you get a little red delete button without a title – probably not what the API intends!